Join two tables such that the joined records have their own valid date range
Assuming I have the two following tables, with their valid date range indicated in the last two columns.
Table: Aircraft



LegID
Aircraft
AFrom
ATo




123
788
2022
2024


123
789
2024
9999



Table: Seat



LegID
Seat
SFrom
STo




123
1A
2021
2023


123
1B
2023
9999



How do I join the two tables such that they form their new valid date range based valid date range of both the tables?
Example:



LegID
Aircraft
Seat
From
To




123
NULL
1A
2021
2022


123
788
1A
2022
2023


123
788
1B
2023
2024


123
789
1B
2024
9999




Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

MS SQL Server @jarlh

you will need to explain much more in detail how you got from your sample data to your expected result

That result doesn't make much sense. How come you want it? Strange design too.

try this
WITH JoinedData AS (
    SELECT
        a.LegID,
        a.Aircraft,
        s.Seat,
        GREATEST(a.AFrom, s.SFrom) AS FromDate,
        LEAST(a.ATo, s.STo) AS ToDate
    FROM
        Aircraft a
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        Seat s
    ON
        a.LegID = s.LegID
        AND a.AFrom <= s.STo
        AND a.ATo >= s.SFrom
),
ExtendedData AS (
    SELECT
        LegID,
        COALESCE(Aircraft, 'NULL') AS Aircraft,
        COALESCE(Seat, 'NULL') AS Seat,
        FromDate,
        ToDate
    FROM
        JoinedData
    WHERE
        FromDate <= ToDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        s.LegID,
        NULL AS Aircraft,
        s.Seat,
        s.SFrom AS FromDate,
        s.STo AS ToDate
    FROM
        Seat s
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Aircraft a
            WHERE
                s.LegID = a.LegID
                AND s.SFrom <= a.ATo
                AND s.STo >= a.AFrom
        )
),
OrderedData AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        LegID,
        Aircraft,
        Seat,
        FromDate,
        ToDate
    FROM
        ExtendedData
)
SELECT
    LegID,
    Aircraft,
    Seat,
    FromDate AS "From",
    ToDate AS "To"
FROM
    OrderedData
ORDER BY
    LegID, FromDate;


A good answer included an explanation in addition to working code

Use CalenDar table.
declare @AirCraft table(LegID int,Aircraft int, AFrom int,ATo int)
insert into @AirCraft values(123,788,2022,2024)
insert into @AirCraft values (123,789,2024,9999)

declare @Seat table(LegID int,  Seat varchar(10),SFrom int,STo int)
insert into @Seat values(123,'1A',2021,2023)
,(123,'1B',2023,9999)

--create calendar table say from 2000 to 2050
-- here small layman sample table

declare @Calendar table(years int)
insert into @Calendar values(2020),(2021),(2022),(2023),(2024)

Declare @CurYear int=year(getdate())

;With CTE as(
select s.LegID,s.Seat,c.years [FromYear], case when s.STo=9999 and
 c.years=@CurYear then 1 else  null end as [ToYear]
From @Seat S
cross apply(select c.YEARs from  @Calendar c where (c.years>=s.SFrom and c.years< s.STo))c
)

select LegID,a.Aircraft, Seat, [FromYear] ,case when ToYear=1 
then 9999 else FromYear+1 end [Toyear]
from CTE C
outer apply(select Aircraft from @AirCraft A where a.LegID=c.LegID 
and (FromYear>= a.AFrom and FromYear<ATo) )a

Note : This is not tested across all sample data.But this can be fix to suit other test scenarios
